# Why does my replace methods throws an error?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the number in the `myArray` to either 'even' or 'odd' but it throws an error that `TypeError: val.replace is not a function`

```
const myArray = [
  [23, 156, 25, 10, 52, 23],

  [12, 100, 23, 56, 81, 93],

  [42.5, 71, 10, 23, 35, 11, 72, 99],

  [11, 100, 99, 102, 13, 8, 12]
];

let arr = myArray.map(item => {
  return item.map(val => {
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
      val.toString();
      val.replace(val, "even");
    } else {
      val.replace(val, "odd");
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr); //TypeError: val.replace is not a function
```

Comment: because `val` is not a string. After converting to the string, you need to reinitialize `val`, then only `replace` will work.

Comment: `val.toString()` doesn't magically mutate variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use replace, you simply need to map

```js
const myArray = [
  [23, 156, 25, 10, 52, 23],

  [12, 100, 23, 56, 81, 93],

  [42.5, 71, 10, 23, 35, 11, 72, 99],

  [11, 100, 99, 102, 13, 8, 12]
];

let arr = myArray.map(item => item.map(val => val % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'))

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the new value.

[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string with the replaced values, but you do not have a strings here.

```js
const myArray = [
  [23, 156, 25, 10, 52, 23],
  [12, 100, 23, 56, 81, 93],
  [42.5, 71, 10, 23, 35, 11, 72, 99],
  [11, 100, 99, 102, 13, 8, 12]
];

let arr = myArray.map(item => {
  return item.map(val => {
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
      return "even";
    } else {
      return "odd";
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following (Check for value if divisible by 0, if yes return **even** else **odd**)

```js
const myArray = [[23, 156, 25, 10, 52, 23], [12, 100, 23, 56, 81, 93], [42.5, 71, 10, 23, 35, 11, 72, 99], [11, 100, 99, 102, 13, 8, 12]];

let arr = myArray.map(item => item.map(val => val%2 === 0 ? "even": "odd"));

console.log(arr);
```

Or you can improve your code as follows

```js
const myArray = [[23, 156, 25, 10, 52, 23], [12, 100, 23, 56, 81, 93], [42.5, 71, 10, 23, 35, 11, 72, 99], [11, 100, 99, 102, 13, 8, 12]];

let arr = myArray.map(item => {
  return item.map(val => {
    if (val % 2 == 0) {
      val = val.toString(); // you need to reassign after toString
      val = val.replace(val, "even"); // you need to reassign after replace
    } else {
      val = val.toString(); // you need to reassign after toString
      val = val.replace(val, "odd"); // you need to reassign after replace
    }
    return val; // finally you need to return the updated value
  });
});

console.log(arr); //Now the right input will be logged
```